# Attendance register using asp classic

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic, time-and-attendance

I am looking for vb script in asp classic as below:

I have one table named "attendance" in MSSQL2005 database which has some records. The table includes 2 columns (`sname, sdate`).

My question is how can I show all records like attendance register, meaning all dates should be in horizontal column as header on top (based on month in selected year if month has 31 date then 31 columns).

In the next row: below date column, if the header date match date from field `sdate` then it should show `"P"` or it should show `"A"`. It's basically  a calendar without daynames.

Unfortunately even thorough search didn't find me any built-in solutions yet

Comment: You need to create your custom Logic to build this. in this you need to find days based on month and Year and then need to show dates and then on each column you need to find student has entry in db or not and then you can show "P"  or "A" based on that.

Comment: by using custom logic, its done :). created calendar function and loop. now its work perfect

Answer (score 1):

here i will show you how to show **attendance register** by passing single month and year value using **vbscript and ASP Classic**

This article may be helpfull to other people who are looking for same solution.

I have 2 tables as below written

1. **Staff:** contain information about staff user in column like (staff_id, Aname,...)
2. **Staff_attendance:** attendance of staff user save in this table with date wise unique row. table has 3 columns(staff_Aid, staff_attn_dt, staff_Att_takenby)

Now i will show you how to retrive all records from "Staff_attendance" table by retriving records from "staff" table as attendance register *(see below given pic)*

[image]

```
<!--#include file="connection.asp"-->
<%
' above include file is to bring data connection which is "MM_connDUdirectory_STRING"
Dim MyMonth 'Month of calendar
Dim MyYear  'Year of calendar
Dim FirstDay 'First day of the month.  0 = Sunday
Dim CurrentDay 'Used to print dates in calendar
Dim Col 'Calendar column
Dim Row 'Calendar row
MyMonth = request.Form("imonth") 
MyYear = request.Form("iyear")

If MyMonth = 0 then MyMonth = Month(Date)
if MyYear = 0 then MyYear = Year(Date)

response.write "<b>" & MonthName(MyMonth) & " " & MyYear & "</b>"
%>

<table width="100%" style="border: #6F6F6F 1px solid; text-align: center;">
<tr>
<td nowrap style="border-bottom: #6F6F6F 1px solid; text-align: center;">&nbsp;&nbsp;Faculty Name&nbsp;&nbsp;</td> 
<%
FirstDay = DateSerial(MyYear, MyMonth, 1)
CurrentDay = 1
For Col = 0 to 30
if CurrentDay > LastDay(MyMonth, MyYear) then
%>

<td style="border: #6F6F6F 1px solid; text-align: center;">&nbsp;</td>
<% else %>
<td style="border: #6F6F6F 1px solid; text-align: center;"><font face='Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif' size='2'><%= CurrentDay %></font></td>

<%
CurrentDay = CurrentDay + 1
End If
Next
'Below i have added additional column header for number of persent (NOP)
%>
<td style="border-bottom: #6F6F6F 1px solid; background-color: #505050; color: #ffffff;"><b>NOP</b></td>
</tr>
<%          
dim Objrs1, str1, objCmd1
Set objCmd1 = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
Set Objrs1   = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
str1 = "SELECT * FROM staff ORDER BY Aname Asc"
With objCmd1
.ActiveConnection = MM_connDUdirectory_STRING
.CommandText = str1
.CommandType = adCmdText
end with 
Objrs1.open objCmd1, , 1, 2

if Objrs1.EOF then
%>
<div class="information-box round">Sorry! Record(s) not Found</div>
<% else %>
<% while not objrs1.EOF %>
<tr>
<td nowrap style="padding: 5px 0 5px 0;border-bottom: #6F6F6F 1px solid;background-color: #F8F9FA; font-size: 13px;">&nbsp;&nbsp;<b><%= objrs1("Aname") %></b>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
<%
FirstDay = DateSerial(MyYear, MyMonth, 1)
CurrentDay = 1
For Col = 1 to 31
if CurrentDay > LastDay(MyMonth, MyYear) then
%>
<td style="border: #6F6F6F 1px solid; text-align: center;">&nbsp;</td>
<% else %>
<td style="border: #6F6F6F 1px solid; text-align: center;background-color: #FFFCCC;"><font face='Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif' size='2'>
<%
'below code to match above retrieved staff record in "Staff_attendance" table
dim Objrs1x, str1x, objCmd1x
Set objCmd1x = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
Set Objrs1x   = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
str1x = "SELECT staff_Aid, staff_attn_dt, staff_Att_takenby FROM Staff_attendance where staff_Aid=? and day(staff_attn_dt)=? and Month(staff_attn_dt)=? and Year(staff_attn_dt)=?"
With objCmd1x
.ActiveConnection = MM_connDUdirectory_STRING
.CommandText = str1x
.CommandType = adCmdText
.Parameters.Append(.CreateParameter("@param4gk1", adInteger, adParamInput, ,objRs1("Aid")))
.Parameters.Append(.CreateParameter("@param4gk22", adVarChar, adParamInput, len(MyYear)))
.Parameters.Append(.CreateParameter("@param4gk2", adVarChar, adParamInput, len(MyMonth)))
.Parameters.Append(.CreateParameter("@param4gk21", adVarChar, adParamInput, len(MyYear)))

.Parameters("@param4gk1").Value = objRs1("Aid")
.Parameters("@param4gk22").Value = Col
.Parameters("@param4gk2").Value = MyMonth
.Parameters("@param4gk21").Value = MyYear
end with 
Objrs1x.open objCmd1x, , 1, 2

if not Objrs1x.EOF then
%>
<span style="color: #0000ff;" title="Taken by user: <%=Objrs1x("staff_Att_takenby")%>"><b>P</b></span></font>
<% else %>
<span style="color: #ff0000;"><b>A</b></span></font>
<%
End If
Objrs1x.close
Set Objrs1x = Nothing
Set objCmd1x = Nothing
%>      
</td>
<%
CurrentDay = CurrentDay + 1
End If
%>
<%
Next
'Below code to show Number of persent (NOP) in column
%>
<td style="border-bottom: #6F6F6F 1px solid; background-color: #505050; color: #ffffff;">
<%
dim Objrs1xq, str1xq, objCmd1xq
Set objCmd1xq = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
Set Objrs1xq   = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
str1xq = "SELECT count(staff_Aid) as nop FROM Staff_attendance where staff_Aid=? and Month(staff_attn_dt)=? and Year(staff_attn_dt)=?"
With objCmd1xq
.ActiveConnection = MM_connDUdirectory_STRING
.CommandText = str1xq
.CommandType = adCmdText
.Parameters.Append(.CreateParameter("@param4gk1x", adInteger, adParamInput, ,objRs1("Aid")))
.Parameters.Append(.CreateParameter("@param4gk2x", adVarChar, adParamInput, len(MyMonth)))
.Parameters.Append(.CreateParameter("@param4gk21x", adVarChar, adParamInput, len(MyYear)))

.Parameters("@param4gk1x").Value = objRs1("Aid")
.Parameters("@param4gk2x").Value = MyMonth
.Parameters("@param4gk21x").Value = MyYear
end with 
Objrs1xq.open objCmd1xq, , 1, 2

if not Objrs1xq.EOF then
%>
<b><%=Objrs1xq("nop")%></b>
<%
End If
Objrs1xq.close
Set Objrs1xq = Nothing
Set objCmd1xq = Nothing
%>      
</td>
</tr>
<%
Objrs1.MoveNext()
Wend
%>
<%
end if
Objrs1.Close
Set Objrs1 = Nothing
%>
</table>
<%
Function MonthName(MyMonth)
Select Case MyMonth
Case 1
MonthName = "January"
Case 2
MonthName = "Febuary"
Case 3
MonthName = "March"
Case 4
MonthName = "April"
Case 5
MonthName = "May"
Case 6
MonthName = "June"
Case 7
MonthName = "July"
Case 8
MonthName = "August"
Case 9
MonthName = "September"
Case 10
MonthName = "October"
Case 11
MonthName = "November"
Case 12
MonthName = "December"
Case Else
MonthName = "ERROR!"
End Select
End Function

Function LastDay(MyMonth, MyYear)
' Returns the last day of the month. Takes into account leap years

Select Case MyMonth
Case 1, 3, 5, 7, 8, 10, 12
LastDay = 31

Case 4, 6, 9, 11
LastDay = 30

Case 2
If IsDate(MyYear & "-" & MyMonth & "-" & "29") Then LastDay = 29 Else LastDay = 28

Case Else
LastDay = 0

End Select
End Function
%>
```